# How to mute the motion tracker sound?

Tags: aliens-vs-predator-2010

The sound the motion tracker plays when there are no targets in range, which sounds like a record skipping, is giving me a headache. How can I mute this sound, and this sound only?

Answer (score 0):

Heyho, i found a solution in [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1547504) thread:

It seems like you cant "mute" the sound but you can replace it.
Get any soundpack for the game on the page moddb.com for example and your basic problem is solved - the annoying sound got replaced.
As next you should be able to delete the sounds you dont want to be replaced one after another.

Now you've got a modified modpack, which alters just one sound - congrats :P

In my Opinion, this belongs to the game/movie and you shouldn't remove the sound as its pretty important for the ambiance, but:
If you really don't want any sound for the tracker, replace the file with an empty sound.

Comment: Replace it with an empty sound how? The files are not in any conventional sound format, but some proprietary nonsense. I've tried some sound replacers, and while they are less annoying, I would still like to remove the sound altogether.

Comment: Im sorry, just to be sure, the sound files are .it files arent they?

Comment: The extension is actually the language code for your version, I'm playing the English version so in my case it is .en.

Comment: I downloaded some soundpacks for the game and their they use .it files.
It would be worth a try to create an empty .it file and rename it to the files "name.language-suffix"

btw. .it files are Impulse Tracker files mostly generated by the eponymous software.

Comment: I've already tried a blank .en file, the sound simply reverts to the game's default. Where do you download this soundpack, and have you successfully opened the file using Impulse Tracker?

Comment: Actually I'm running on Linux and cant install the software as I tried yesterday :/
I guess you really just created a new text file and called it "whatever.en"? This should not work :)
It's not just about how its called, but also about what its content is. Even in an correct generated empty file there is not the same thing inside as in an empty .txt file.
There are some pretty important file specifications used as header.

The most easiest way may be to try the software called audacity, which supports many file-types. It's likely to refuse the work, but at least its not an Assmbler Programm :/

Comment: So where can I download that mod?

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: I know how to search for **a** mod, that's how I got the soundpack that had .en files; I want to see the specific mod you're talking about.